# PHP to Update MySQL Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

First off, just wanted to say I'm a novice at this type of coding, although I'm hopeful that I'll eventually make sense of it all with a little guidance.

I have a MySQL database table (promotion) that stores a bunch of redemption codes for various products (for a give away contest). The idea is, the first person to enter the redemption code wins the product, and their info should be stored in the "promotion" table.

The table's columns are: redeem_id (Auto Increment field), redeem_code, redeemer_email, redeemer_first_name, redeemer_last_name, and redeem_date_time.

Initially, the redeem_id and redeem_code fields are the only ones with any data. What I'd like to happen is when a user enters their information (name, email, etc) and submit a redemption code, their info will populate the rest of the row for that particular code. If anyone else tries to submit a code that has already been redeemed, they should receive an error message - likewise for an invalid code (i.e. a code that does not exist in the table).

The PHP code I have so far is:

```
<?php
function get_promotion_by_redeem_code($redeem_code)
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM promotion WHERE redeem_code= '".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_code)."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

return $row;
}

function redeem_promotion($email,$first_name,$last_name,$redeem_date_time,$redeem_code)
{
    $query = 'UPDATE promotion
    SET redeemer_email=".mysql_real_escape_string($email).", redeemer_first_name=".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name).", redeemer_last_name=".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name).", redeem_date_time=NOW(), WHERE redeem_code=".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_code)."';
    $insert = mysql_query($query);
    return $insert;
}

$email=$_POST['e_mail'];
$first_name=$_POST['f_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['l_name'];
$redeem_code=$_POST['v_code'];

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db', 'pw');
mysql_select_db('db', $connection);

$promotion = get_promotion_by_redeem_code($redeem_code);

if ($promotion) {
    if (!$promotion['redeemer_email']) {
        redeem_promotion($email,$first_name,$last_name,$redeem_date_time,$redeem_code);
        echo 'Congratulations, you have successfully claimed this item!';
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, this item has already been redeemed.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, you have entered an incorrect claim code. Please use your browser\'s back button to try again.';
}

mysql_close($connection);  
?>
```

It works as expected when I enter an invalid claim code, or if a code's row has been previously populated.
When it doesn't work, is when someone goes to redeem the item for the first time. Essentially, it will show the "Congratulations" message, however the table doesn't get updated for the submitted information. Therefore, no matter how many times the correct code is entered, the user will receive the "Congratulations" message.

I'm fairly certain that the error is in the redeem_promotion() function, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Simple things to try when a mysql operation isn't working: 1) echo mysql_error() right after the query and see if there's an error. 2) echo the text of the query and see if it looks right and all the variables are being set. 3) run the query in mysql directly and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have add an **extra comma(,)** before `WHERE` clause. Thats the mistake, i think.

```
function redeem_promotion($email,$first_name,$last_name,$redeem_date_time,$redeem_code)
{
    $query = 'UPDATE promotion
    SET redeemer_email=".mysql_real_escape_string($email).", 
        redeemer_first_name=".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name).", 
        redeemer_last_name=".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name).", 
        redeem_date_time=NOW() 
    WHERE redeem_code=".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_code)."';

    **OR**

    $query = "UPDATE promotion
    SET redeemer_email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', 
        redeemer_first_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."', 
        redeemer_last_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name)."', 
        redeem_date_time=NOW() 
    WHERE redeem_code='".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_code)."'";

    $insert = mysql_query($query);
    return $insert;
}
```

Comment: I took the comma out, but the table still doesn't update when entering a correct code.

Comment: There is no variable named `$redeem_date_time` when you call the `function`. Is it any problem?

Comment: Another thing, you can try `reversing` single quote and double qoute.

Comment: OK I changed the function slightly to: `$query = 'UPDATE promotion SET...redeem_date_time=".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_date_time)." WHERE redeem_code=".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_code)."';`
And then named the variable $redeem_date_time
`$redeem_date_time='NOW()';`
Still produces the same result.

Comment: Change to:

 `$query = "UPDATE promotion
    SET redeemer_email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', 
        redeemer_first_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."', 
        redeemer_last_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name)."', 
        redeem_date_time=NOW() 
    WHERE redeem_code='".mysql_real_escape_string($redeem_code)."'"`

Comment: @TusharDhoot if a strange man walks up and gives you a hug some day, it might be me. Thank you so much for your help! P.S. I won't actually do that :-)

Comment: No problem, but it was really @sarwar026 's effort. :)

Comment: Thanks to @TusharDhoot and `scd1982`